# GCM - Getting SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE when registering programmatically the broadcast receiver

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm integrating GCM with an Android app to receive push notifications. Everything works fine, I'm able to receive the notifications. The thing is that I receive these notifications even when the app **is not running**, but I need to receive them **only** when the app **is running**.

So I thought that if I will register the broadcast receiver programmatically in application, and unregister it in `onDestroy()` will do the job.
However this does not work, when trying to get the registration id it returns SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE.

This is the broadcast receiver declared in manifest that works, but I receive the notifications all time:

```
 <receiver android:name=".service.MyBroadcastReceiver"
                  android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <category android:name="com.testgcm"/>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And this is how I programmatically create it, but receive the above error:

```
receiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE");
filter.addCategory("com.testgcm");
registerReceiver(receiver, filter, "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND", null);
```

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong? 
Or perhaps there's better way to make so that to receive the notifications only when the app is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this has less to do with the fact that I am registering the `BroadcastReceiver` programmatically, but in fact it represents a failure operation to register.

Here's what docs say:

> When the application receives a
>   com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION intent with the error
>   extra set as SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, it should retry the failed
>   operation (register or unregister).
>
> In the simplest case, if your application just calls register and GCM
>   is not a fundamental part of the application, the application could
>   simply ignore the error and try to register again the next time it
>   starts. Otherwise, it should retry the previous operation using
>   exponential back-off. In exponential back-off, each time there is a
>   failure, it should wait twice the previous amount of time before
>   trying again. If the register (or unregister) operation was
>   synchronous, it could be retried in a simple loop. However, since it
>   is asynchronous, the best approach is to schedule a pending intent to
>   retry the operation.